# Created Tiled Print Layouts with Page Overlap in CorelDraw 2021

Tags: pdf, layers, corel-draw, affinity-designer, tiles

I draft sewing patterns in CorelDraw 2021 and I'm attempting to create an 8.5" x 11" paper size tiled PDF that has some overlap with the pages to the right and underneath...for those who don't know, this is done in the sewing pattern world to assemble a sewing pattern without having to cut anything off of each page. In Adobe Illustrator and Affinity Designer, you can just line up a bunch of 8.5" x 11" artboards and overlap them on two sides, then dump the entire pattern on top of the artboards.

I've pulled it off in Affinity Designer, but I find Designer very annoying to work with and the exported PDF has the size layers all cut up...one for each size AND page...for 16 sizes and 16 pages, so it results in 256 layers. Obviously not what I want!

I can't seem to figure out the equivalent process in CorelDraw; this is where I draft, so I would prefer to keep everything in one spot if possible. When I paste the pattern on top of my overlapping Pages, it only shows up on one page and not all of them. Using Master Layer also doesn't work, as it just makes all the pages the same.

I would love if someone could help me with this...I have attached a screenshot of the PDF I made using Affinity Designer to show you what I'm trying to do. Again, the layers repeat in the  list on the left for each size and page, which is not what I want, but otherwise the appearance of the PDF will hopefully show you what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Trimless Sewing Pattern PDF]

[image: Two Page View]

Comment: You might be able to do this in Adobe Acrobat Reader (which is free). Export as a PDF first obviously, open in Reader, then see instructions here: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html#:~:text=Print%20posters%20and%20banners%20using%20Acrobat%20or%20Reader.,pages%20in%20the%20PDF%20file.%20%20See%20More.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, you definitely can. That's how I've been doing it for my own personal use for years, but unfortunately in the sewing world, if you want to make patterns to sell, they pretty much have to look like my screenshots out of the box, so customers can just hit print :(

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be a bit chaotic because I don't have the 2021 version and it is in Spanish. So the names of the options will have a different name than the one I am writing in (parentheses), but the process would be similar.

I will try to update the answer when I am on the other computer that has Corel Draw in English.

Go to File > (Preliminary Presentation?)

[image]

Press the (Print as Mosaic?) icon.

[image]

Go to (Preferences) > General

[image]

On the Layout tab play with the values on the (Mosaic Overlap?)

[image]

Play with additional checkboxes, such as (Include cut marks?)

When you press Ok, you can see that each page now overlaps with another.

[image]

Now, when you print the file to a PDF each page will have that overlap.